# flatMap a Dictionary of Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flatmap

I have an `NSEnumerator` which contains nested key value objects like this:

```
 [ "posts" :
    ["randonRootKey1" :
        ["randomChildKey1" : [:] ]
    ], 
    ["randonRootKey2" :
        ["randomChildKey2" : [:] ],
        ["randomChildKey3" : [:] ],
    ]  
]

- posts
-- user1
--- posts
----post
-- user2
-- posts
--- post
```

I want to extract all posts of all users in one array ... last child and all parents are dictionaries

I want to flatMap it to be :

```
[
        ["randomChildKey1" : [:] ],
        ["randomChildKey2" : [:] ],
        ["randomChildKey3" : [:] ]
]
```

Note that I have extracted the objects of each root dictionary.

I have tried :

```
let sub = snapshot.children.flatMap({$0})
```

but does not seem to work

Comment: Can you give us a valid swift syntax for the input, and the output you want?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov it's just a dictionary with random keys that contains other dictionaries with random keys

Comment: Again... Can you please give us a valid swift syntax for the input, and the output you want?

Comment: Do you have something like: `[["KOfgD9KrcCZYZB9JB5W"],["KOvJXpwckWfRs_IhguP"],[["-KNnRRu7Wv51bL_uvccp"],["-KNrlMKcNf1sZHzJvJrO"],["-KNrlf2e4PVegKgdupso"]]]`, rigth? So: `let flat = collections.flatMap { $0 }` will print something like: `["KOfgD9KrcCZYZB9JB5W", "KOvJXpwckWfRs_IhguP", ["-KNnRRu7Wv51bL_uvccp"], ["-KNrlMKcNf1sZHzJvJrO"], ["-KNrlf2e4PVegKgdupso"]]`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov see updated question

Comment: @KlevisonMatias I have updated the question

Comment: @iOSGeek That's 3 nesting levels deep. Is this intentional?

Comment: I receive it from firebase

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I have updated my question with more clear structure

Comment: @iOSGeek Have you even tried compiling that?

Answer (score 1):

```
 let input: [String: [String: [String: Any]]] = ["posts":
    [
        "randonRootKey1": [
            "randomChildKey1": [:],
        ],
        "randonRootKey2": [
            "randomChildKey2": [:],
            "randomChildKey3": [:],
        ]
    ]
]

var output = [String: Any]()

for dictionary in input["posts"]!.values {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        output[key] = value
    }
}

print(output)
```

> ["randomChildKey3": [:], "randomChildKey2": [:], "randomChildKey1": [:]]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input to be in this format

```
let input: [String: [String: [String: Any]]] = ["posts":
    [
        "randonRootKey1": [
            "randomChildKey1": [:],
        ],
        "randonRootKey2": [
            "randomChildKey2": [:],
            "randomChildKey3": [:],
        ]
    ]
]
```

Using this

```
let output = input.flatMap{$0.1}.flatMap{$0.1}
```

You will get the desired output

> [("randomChildKey1", [:]), ("randomChildKey2", [:]), ("randomChildKey3", [:])]

If you want to convert the tuple to dictionary use `reduce`

```
let output = input.flatMap{$0.1}.flatMap{$0.1}.reduce([String: Any]())
{
    (var dict, tuple) in
    dict.append([tuple.0: tuple.1])
    return dict
}
```

> [["randomChildKey1": {}], ["randomChildKey2": {}], ["randomChildKey3": {}]]

Comment: is is safe ? what happens what the structure is not like expected in the first `flatMap` or second one ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the output of this is an array of key/value tuples, and not dictionaries.

Comment: @iOSGeek Can you give us an example of what you mean by not having the expected structure?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Thanks for the heads up, I just fixed the issue.

Comment: @AhmedBaracat what if randonRootKey2 will be an empty array ?

Comment: @iOSGeek it won't be flattened, the output will only include randomChildKey1.